# Convert IntStream to int

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have never used streams in java before and am now trying to test how to accomplish simple examples with stream.

I want to return a random int int the range of 60-120 and have tried this:

```
return new Random().ints(1,60,121);
```

But I understand that I have to also convert it back to a int again but can't figure out how.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--

Comment: `new Random().ints(1, 60, 121).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: If you want just one value, you wouldn't use a Stream. `int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(61) + 60;` (note: this creates no objects.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey or `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60, 121)`

Comment: Use `nextInt` from `Random` to get a single random int. Why are you creating a int stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you created a Stream with a single element, you can use `findFirst()` to get that element:

```
int randInt = new Random().ints(1,60,121).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

That said, it doesn't make sense to create an `IntStream` for the sake of producing a single random number. You can use `Random`'s `nextInt()` instead.

If you want to generate multiple random integers, using an `IntStream` would make more sense. In that case you can convert the generated `IntStream` to an array:

```
int[] randInts = new Random().ints(1000,60,121).toArray();
```